# At what time in windows.performance.timing, a browser loading spinner will turns into blue color and rotate clockwise direction

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I hitting a url ,at the top I have seen grey color loading spinner and it is rotating anti clockwise direction. After some time a grey color turn into blue color and rotating clock wise direction.
I want some information that in which state of windows.performance.timing  a loading spinner turns into blue and do clockwise rotation???

Comment: We would need significantly more information such as which browser; version of that browser etc..  Otherwise I could just say "Tuesday" and that would be correct given my browser does that on a Tuesday.

Comment: Mozilla latest version browsers